# Why to leave home after death in some nakshatras?

Tags: death, nakshatra

It is said that people who die under Rohini Nakshatra, their children have to leave home for one year. Is it true?

If yes, than why it is so only for some Nakshatras?

Comment: Can you post the source of that info also?

Comment: I tried searching for the source in the internet. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any. I heard this statement, which I have posted as question, from some one.

Comment: I don't think the relevant scripture will mention the reasons as to why.They will only prescribe what are the things that are needed to be done .i.e the remedies.